# Generating apk from github source in android studio

Tags: github, android-studio, apk

I am trying the build the package file (apk) in Android Studio 1.1 (JRE 1.8) from the following github project.

https://github.com/EspressifApp/IOT-Espressif-Android

But when i try to build/compile the project APK is not generated. Am I missing something or do I need to do anything special other than just trying to build the project from the Build-->Make Project option in android studio.